# error using inert php plugin wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, session

I want to create login page for admin and worker, and each of them will have different content table in their page once they logged in.

I've installed `insert php` plugin to write code in page directly.

I am using session for login and I want to use record set to create custom table in each page.

I created a code in dreamweaver then post it in page text.

I have created this code but it didn't work as php and didn't logged in and shows code in the page.

```
[insert_php]
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start(); // Starting Session
    $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
        } else {
            // Define $username and $password
            $username=$_POST['username'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "lujcarwa", "lcarwash2015");

            // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
            $username = stripslashes($username);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);

            // Selecting Database
            $db = mysqli_select_db("login", $connection);

            // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
            $query = mysqli_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
            $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if ($rows == 1) {
                $_SESSION['login']=$username; // Initializing Session
                header("location: profile.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
            } else {
                $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
            }

            mysqli_close($connection); // Closing Connection
        }
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        header("location: profile.php");
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "lujcarwa_washer", "dj0P7]w4S]");

    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysqli_select_db("lujcarwa_washer", $connection);
    session_start();// Starting Session

    // Storing Session
    $user_check=$_SESSION['login'];

    // SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
    $ses_sql=mysqli_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
    $login_session =$row['username'];

    if(!isset($login_session)){
        mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
        header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
    }

[insert_php/]
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1> Login </h1>
    <div id="login">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
          <label>UserName :</label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <br />
          <input id="name" name="username" placeholder="username" type="text">
          <br />
          <label>
            <br>Password</label>
          <br />
          <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not known with the [insert_php] plugin but it looks like it's a issue with not closing you [insert_php] tag like this [/insert_php] at the end of your php.

**Edit:**

You are closing it like:

```
[insert_php/] //While it should be: [/insert_php]
```

Hope this helps you out.

**Edit:**

I just took a look at the plugin description and saw this in the FAQ:

**Why can't I set cookies or do a browser redirect?**
With PHP, cookies are set in the web page header lines, before any page content is processed. **Redirects**, too, are done in the header lines. When PHP code is within a post or a page, all the header lines have already been sent, along with part of the content. *At that point, it is too late to set cookies or redirect with PHP*

So it looks like you can't use this plugin to redirect the user at login.
I would suggest just to write the php in your template folder in a custom page template or header file.

Hope this helped!

Comment: i correct it 
still same problem did not function as php

Comment: Found some info in the Plugin Documentation about problems with redirects, see my edit above.